# Eclipse autocomplete showing the proposals without filling them

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I have just installed the Eclipse IDE and I searched on the internet how to configure the autocomplete. I found a good method and after that I implemented it. But, now I'm very curious if the autocomplete can be set to show the proposals without filling them if I don't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing your question is that when you press the shotcut of automatic complete,then it fill the code automatically without a confirmation
the reason is that the result of your attemp to complete is just only one,so there is a mechanism that when the result of the attemp to complete is just only one,then it will be automatically filled
but you can set up this mechanism in in the following way

windows---preferences---java---editor---contentassist---insert single proposals automatically

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I mean that when I write for example "String name" the auto-complete window shows "nameString" and if I press "Space" to move on it change my variable from "name" in "nameString". This is just an example, but the point is that I want to use the autocomplete just when I press a key like Enter. At the same time, I wish that the window with proposals to show always not just when I press CTRL+SPACE

Comment: Then you should go to windows---preferences---java---editor---contentassist,and in the Auto Activation part,untick "enable auto activation" will meet your need,in anytime it will not automatically come up proposal window without press the shotcut.And in "auto activation triggers for java",you can setup which characters will automatically come up proposal.Secondly, the shotcut of the window with proposals can be set up in "windows---preferences---general---keys",the shotcut name is "content assist",hope it will help :-)

Comment: Thank you, I think that this is the best answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you press CTRL + Space it should show the autocomplete and you just have to press enter for it to fill in.